# Failing to connect to dockerised postgres database using Python container

Tags: python, database, postgresql, docker, psycopg2

I have a database created using docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  appacc:
    build:
      context: AcceptMessage
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    networks:
      - my-network
  applog:
    build:
      context: LogonPage
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - my-network
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: amigoscode
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

networks:
  my-network:
  postgres:

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

And I have a Python script to retrieve sample data from this database:

```
import psycopg2

db_params = {
    "host": "postgres",
    "port": 5432,
    "database": "dbname",
    "user": "amigoscode",
    "password": "password"
}

try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(**db_params)
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    query = "SELECT * FROM usert;"
    cursor.execute(query)
    table = cursor.fetchall()
    print("Tables: ", table)

except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
    print("Error while connecting to PostgreSQL:", error)

finally:
    if connection:
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("PostgreSQL connection closed.")
```

I run this Python code using Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY main.py .
RUN pip install psycopg2-binary
CMD ["python", "main.py"]

# docker build -t db-connector .
# docker run db-connector
```

While it works as I run it from console after setting host to localhost, I cannot get this to run and retrieve data using Docker reulting in:

```
Error while connecting to PostgreSQL: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 27, in <module>     
    if connection:
NameError: name 'connection' is not defined
```

Comment: Is you're python container attached to the 'postgres' network?

Comment: I ran it using 
`docker build -t db-connector .
docker run --rm -it --network=my_network db-connector`
And nothing has changed

Comment: Well, that network 'my_network' is not the network the postgres container is attached to.  I don't know why you are using two different networks, but if you do you need to use them correctly.

Comment: Now I have one network and the same thing is still happening

Comment: Works for me.  Or at least fails at a later point, where it tries to connect to "dbname" despite that not being the name of your database (it defaulting to "postgres"). It is hard to tell exactly what you are doing, as you have made changes to the code but didn't show us the new code with the changes, just described changes.